# Thread-safety of Cassandra BoundStatement

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra, thread-safety, prepared-statement

[This doc guides how to use Cassandra prepared and bound statements.](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/statements/prepared/)

It says:

> You should prepare only once, and cache the PreparedStatement in your
>   application (it is thread-safe).  ... BoundStatement is not
>   thread-safe. You can reuse an instance multiple times with different
>   parameters, but only from a single thread and only if you use
>   synchronous calls:

```
BoundStatement bound = ps1.bind();

// This is safe:
bound.setString("sku", "324378");
session.execute(bound);

bound.setString("sku", "324379");
session.execute(bound);

// This is NOT SAFE. executeAsync runs concurrently with your code, so the first execution might actually read the
// values after the second setString call, and you would insert 324381 twice:
bound.setString("sku", "324380");
session.executeAsync(bound);

bound.setString("sku", "324381");
session.executeAsync(bound);
```

It's clear that above is not thread safe, but if we change the code this way:

```
BoundStatement bound1 = ps1.bind();
BoundStatement bound2 = ps1.bind();

bound1.setString("sku", "324380");
session.executeAsync(bound1);

bound2.setString("sku", "324381");
session.executeAsync(bound2);
```

That is: Use common PreparedStatement for several threads and every thread uses its own BoundStatement.

1) Is this thread safe?

2) Is this otherwise recommended way to go for parallel execution with prepared statements? Or are BoundStatements expensive / slow to create / consume lots of memory etc reasons to keep the number of them low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is that if you are thinking to use the same `PreparedStatement` object multiple times but with different parameters each time bounded using different `BoundStatement` object then it is thread safe because `PreparedStatement` is thread safe so you can resuse it multiple threads and `BoundStatement` is not thread safe so you are having different object each time.

Just to be clear - so, your thread 1 will create your prepare statement using `ps1 = session.prepare("insert into product (sku, description) values (?, ?)");` and all other threads will use this `ps1` object to create their own `BoundStatement` object because each will have its own values to be passed, for example:

Thread 1 will bind and execute as (notice that using same `ps1` object):

```
BoundStatement bound = ps1.bind().setString("sku", "001").setString("description", "LCD screen"); 
session.execute(bound);
```

Thread 2 will bind and execute as (notice that using same `ps1` object):

```
BoundStatement bound = ps1.bind().setString("sku", "002").setString("description", "TFT screen"); 
session.execute(bound);
```

Thread 3 will bind and execute as (notice that using same `ps1` object):

```
BoundStatement bound = ps1.bind().setString("sku", "003").setString("description", "LED screen"); 
session.execute(bound);
```

---

**In nutshell**: Major performance cost is incurred while creating the `PreparedStatement` object because it take a round trip to DB server (see below depiction), so you reuse the same and it is thread safe, while you create a separate `BoundStatement` each time because it is not thread safe and also it is not a heavy object to create and do not take a round trip to DB server.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Hope they add this piece of information into the next version of Cassandra manual.